# Interpreting Q-Q plot and transforming data

Tags: r, qq-plot

I'm running 'plot(lux.leaf.model)' to check my assumptions of an lm, and to me the Q-Q plot looked off (1st photo). I know it is subjective visualizing the distribution and could use an expert opinion on what to do here. I have a couple questions:

1) is my original Q-Q plot bad enough to necessitate transforming my data? (it has that S pattern, maybe bimodal?)
2) is a log transformation of the y variable suitable?

> lm.model <- lm(leaf_lux ~ session + surface, data)
>
> lm.model <- lm(log(leaf_lux) ~ session + surface, data)

After transforming (2nd photo), the Q-Q plot still doesn't look great (but maybe good enough? Or, maybe the original was good enough?). I've done quite a bit of googling and can't find anything that clearly answers my question. Thank you.

[image: Without log-transforming (original)]

[image: After log-transforming the y variable]

Comment: Because of the clear indication of heteroskedasticity, you can't assess normality by plotting all the residuals; a mixture of variances with a normal distribution will produce a heavier tail when aggregated. Some lack of fit in the mean complicates that even further. There's an order to the first three plots. If the top left one is okay then you can interpret the bottom left one. If that's *also* okay, you can interpret the top right one.

Comment: Thank you. If I can't assess normality of residuals due to heteroskedasticity, Is there a different test I can run (other than lm)?

Comment: `lm` is not itself a test of anything - it fits a linear model. What are your trying to do? Under what assumptions? -- this sounds like an entirely new question

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: You mentioned "expert opinion". I wouldn't consider myself an expert, but I do have some experience on working with linear transformations and data normalization vis a vis QQ-plots.*

Regarding question 1 on whether it's bad enough (or rather good enough), it depends on your final objective. For your case, it looks like your efforts to correct your QQ-plot hasn't helped your objective. So I suppose the answer to question 1 is, yes the original QQ-plot is good enough, because your transformation hasn't brought you closer to your actual goal. At least that's my opinion, I could be mistaken on understanding your objective.

As a side note, the first QQ-plot looks one-sided to me, not S-shaped.

Regarding question 2, the log transformation has made the QQ-plot slightly better. I can't think of a clear-cut answer to what the best approach may be. So the answer to this question would be that it's probably okay, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your analysis. I like the idea of not transforming my data (mostly because I got the exact results I was looking for).